# Several stays: many-to-many relationship

Tags: database-design, ms-access, relational-theory

Could you please help me with the following problem? I'm a total novice in DB design.

I have a table with researchers who visit our university. They come for some period of time (from, till). Now, how can I save in the database if somebody came several times? I have an entry already for a particular person and need to add some other stays and be able to see them in a form.

My idea was: this must be a many-to-many relationship. Ok. Then I need a third table Researcher/Stay. And then I don't know what to do next. In Stay-table "from+till" is a key. I haven't seen examples with double-value key in a many-to-many relationship and don't know what to do next.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your diagram above what you have is a one to many, not a many to many relationship.  You have your Researcher table and your Stay table.  If you add the researcher id in the stay table to the primary key you have a relationship of:

Researcher.ResearcherId -> Stay.ResearcherId

Where a given researcher can have multiple stays.  For example

Researcher John Smith has an Id of 2.

In the stay table you would have

```
From       Till       ResearcherId
1/1/2013   1/5/2013   2
2/6/2013   3/1/2013   2
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

To further [Kenneth Fisher](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/20225/kenneth-fisher)'s answer, the following shows two tables, one for Researchers, and one for their stays.  Multiple stays are allowed for each researcher.

```
CREATE TABLE Researchers (
    ResearcherID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT 
        PK_Researchers IDENTITY(1,1)
    , ResearcherName NVARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Stays (
    StayID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT PK_Stays 
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , StayFrom DATETIME
    , StayTo DATETIME
    , ResearcherID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_Stays_ResearcherID 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Researchers (ResearcherID) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION 
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

INSERT INTO Researchers (ResearcherName) VALUES ('Max');
INSERT INTO Researchers (ResearcherName) VALUES ('John');

INSERT INTO Stays (StayFrom, StayTo, ResearcherID) 
    VALUES ('2013-09-01T00:00:00', '2013-09-15T00:00:00', 1);
INSERT INTO Stays (StayFrom, StayTo, ResearcherID) 
    VALUES ('2013-09-20T00:00:00', '2013-10-05T00:00:00', 1);

INSERT INTO Stays (StayFrom, StayTo, ResearcherID) 
    VALUES ('2013-09-03T00:00:00', '2013-09-05T00:00:00', 2);
INSERT INTO Stays (StayFrom, StayTo, ResearcherID) 
    VALUES ('2013-10-02T00:00:00', '2013-10-05T12:00:00', 2);

SELECT * FROM Researchers;
SELECT * FROM Stays;
```

Results:

[image]